# Calling previously defined function from new scope in SpiderMonkey

Tags: spidermonkey

I am embedding SpiderMonkey in our application and I have a question about scopes. What I am doing is:

1. Create a global object for my whole app
2. Calling JS_EvaluateScript that contains a number of functions that I want to be global for the whole App.
3. Creating a JSObject specific to the "Active Document"
4. Running a a document specific script using JS_EvaluateScript with the 'this' object as the Document.

Here is the problem:

If a function was defined in Step 2 such as:

```
function test()
{
    console.println(this);
}
```

and then the document script contains:

```
test();
```

The output that I see is [object Root] where I would expect to see [object Doc].

Answer (score 1):

> 4. Running a a document specific script using JS_EvaluateScript with the 'this' object as the Document.

For this step, instead of using `JS_EvaluateScript`, you'll should compile the script with `JS_CompileScript`, and then execute it with `JS_ExecuteScript`. The extra step is necessary to supply a different `this` for execution, instead of fixing one at evaluation. Your call to `JS_ExecuteScript` will look like:

```
JS::AutoObjectVector scopeChain(cx);
scopeChain.append(your_document); // your_document will serve as 'this'
JS_ExecuteScript(cx, scopeChain, script, rval);
```

Comment: Which script should I compile? The global one or the document specific one or both? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. You can keep doing what you're doing for the global object methods (Step 2 in your question). When you compile the code for anything that shouldn't use your global as "this" (Step 4 in your example) then you'll need to setup an explicit scope chain as detailed here. The global object is implicitly in the scope chain, so you just need to add your object representing your document (your Step 3) as the first element appended to your scope chain, and it will serve as "this".

Comment: It looks like that function is new. We are still using SpiderMonkey 24 and we will not be able to upgrade for some time. Can you think of anyway to accomplish this with the older SpiderMonkey?

Answer (score 0):

Brad Werth gave a correct answer for SpiderMonkey since version 36. The solution was similar in older versions. Use `JS_ExecuteScript(JSContext *cx, JS::HandleObject obj...)` where obj is a scope object.